# how to change Properties of JAVA VENDOR

Tags: java

i am trying but not really getting how to solve this query.

how do i change properties of  java vendor so that java vendor is SEECS, NUST instead of Sun Microsoft Inc?

Comment: Provide some context. As as your question is not clear at all.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Only way you would be able to do that is to find out where this value is in the core java code, decompile that class, change the value, compile it and replace the class-file in your installation. This however isn't a very portable way.

Comment: This is set by the JVM at startup. Why do you need to change it?

Comment: SEECS, NUST did not create the VM, so SEECS, NUST is not the vendor.  Don't change it.

Comment: What are you trying to change?  All the current releases say "Oracle"

Comment: Some programs look at the Vendor and if you change it, they will not work. (As Oracle discovered in Java 6 update 24)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I want to know where I can get a JVM from Sun Microsoft Inc!

Comment: @chrylis lol, I missed that typo. :D

Comment: Is this an assignment where you are deliberately supposed to try to violate the normal value of java.vendor to see if it can be done?

Answer (score 3):

The [java.vendor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) property is intended to describe the vendor of the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) NOT the java program being executed. Unless you are writing a JRE implementation you should not change this property. If you are writing a JRE then it is easy.

Comment: i am doing a project on Java Security Manager. for that i need to change property of java vendor from Sun microsoft In to SEECS, NUST(which is name of my dept and university). for that i was asking for java code statement as to how m suppose to do that

Comment: below is the properties.java class that i created in Java Security manager project

Comment: below is the properties.java class that i created in Java Security manager project import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
public class PropertiesTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  FileInputStream propFile = new FileInputStream("myProperties.txt");
  Properties p = new Properties(System.getProperties() );
  p.load(propFile);
  System.setProperties(p);
  System.getProperties().list(System.out);
 }
}

Comment: If you have extra information, please edit the question rather than using comments.