# Is it possible for property "java.vendor" to change?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change java.vendor property inside my Android app. I tried  `System.setProperty("string", "java.vendor");` but it does not change the value of the property.
Am I doing something wrong here? Is there any other way?
Thanks!

Comment: your `setProperty` should be `System.setProperty("java.vendor", "somevalue")`

Comment: @Tina Looke i answered first.. awww.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[java.vendor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) is `JRE vendor name`.

Also refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737277/how-to-change-properties-of-java-vendor) for more details.

As per javaDoc,

> ```
> First @param      key   the name of the system property.
> Second @param      value the value of the system property.
> ```

Below code snippet works,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Original = " + System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
        System.setProperty("java.vendor", "ankur");
        System.out.println("Changed = " + System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
    }
```

**output**

```
Original = Oracle Corporation
Changed = ankur
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure, that it use to be, as:

```
System.setProperty("java.vendor", "string");
```

According to [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), the first argument is the key, which is `java.vendor` exactly.